# Angular 4 - RouteReuseStrategy Performance Issue ngDestory not fire

Tags: angular

In my Angular 4 application I have used **RouteReuseStrategy** to store route.

My application has too much memory leak due to this store route because it doesn't call ngOnDestroy() lifehook event when I move to other route.

Following is my RouteReuseStrategy implemented interface and route.config

```
import {RouteReuseStrategy, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, DetachedRouteHandle} from '@angular/router';

export class CustomReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {

    handlers: {[key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle} = {};

    shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        //console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:shouldDetach', route);
        return !!route.data && !!(route.data as any).shouldDetach;
    }

    store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
        //console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:store', route, handle);
        this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path] = handle;
    }

    shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        //console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:shouldAttach', route);
        return !!route.routeConfig && !!this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path];
    }

    retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
        //console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:retrieve', route);
        if (!route.routeConfig) { return null; }
        return this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path];
    }

    shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        //console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:shouldReuseRoute', future, curr);
        return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
    }

}
```

app.routing.js

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { MapComponent } from './components/map/map.component';
import {AuthGuard} from "./components/user-profiles/authentication.component";

const ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'maps', pathMatch: 'full' , canActivate:[AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'maps', component: MapComponent , canActivate:[AuthGuard], data: { shouldDetach: true} },
];
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES);
```

Any suggestion what can be done to release the memory ?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16713) might be relevant/useful.

Comment: Thanks Jeto for quick reference link but I don't see the concrete solution in that link. People have discussed about what they did on trial basis but not sure on solution.

Comment: you've kind of got conflicting goals here. you want component reuse but you want to destroy components, can't have it both ways.  You need to define your goals a little better

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem in my application using route reuse strategy.

My solution was not to destroy components right away(I think if I do so then why use a custom route reuse. So I would destroy them after the handlers dictionary reached a certain size.

In the component I would implement a ngOnDestroy() function to unsubscribe from all my observables.

I also assume this solution would only work for unnamed router outlets, aka 'primary'.

I'm using angular 8, but I think this would work for previous versions.

Code Sample: ( I put this in the store function)

```
if (this.handlers.size == 4 ) { 
            // Loop on all of the components
            this.handlers.forEach((value: any, key: string) => {
                (<any>this.handlers.get(key))
                          .contexts.get('primary').outlet.component.ngOnDestroy();
            });
            this.handlers.clear(); // clear the list to start over.
        }
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: okay I have tried this meaning that the ngDestroy does actually get called. But after looking into the heap, I realized that even after ngDestroy is called the components keep increasing in memory. They are never really removed. I do not believe there is any solution yet to this. For more reference check https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16713